# (Hints please) Prove that $\psi(E)=(\mu\times\lambda)(E)$ for every $E\in S\times T$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given that $(X,S,\mu)$ and $(Y,T,\lambda)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces with the measure $\psi$ defined on $S\times T$ such that $\psi(A\times B)=\mu(A)\lambda(B)$ whenever $A\in S$ and $B\in T$. How should I go about attempting to prove that $\psi(E)=(\mu\times\lambda)(E)$ for every $E\in S\times T$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. Recall (or prove) that the product sigma-algebra $S \otimes T$ is generated by $S \times T$, i.e. $$S \otimes T = \sigma(A \times B; A \in S, B \in T).$$
2. Recall the theorem on uniqueness of measures.
3. Deduce from the fact that the measures $\psi$ and $(\mu \times \lambda)$ coincide on sets of the form $E=A \times B$, $A \in S$, $B \in T$, and the first two steps that $\psi(E) = (\mu \times \lambda)(E)$ for all $E \in S \otimes T$.

Comment: ...Can you please tell me which theorem you are talking about in $2$......I have managed to prove that $\psi(A\times B)=\mu\times \lambda(A\times B)$ for all $A \in S$ and $B \in T$. But how can I conclude that these two measures also agree on (the smallest $\sigma$- algebra generated by these rectangles $A \times B$) $S \times T$?

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh Let $\mu$, $\nu$ be two measures on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a generator of $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{G})=\mathcal{A}$. Assume that $\mathcal{G}$ is $\cap$-stable (that is, $G,H \in \mathcal{G}$ implies $G \cap H \in \mathcal{G}$) and that there exists a sequence $(G_k)_{k \geq 1} \subset \mathcal{G}$ such that $G_k \uparrow X$. If $$\forall G \in \mathcal{G}: \mu(G)=\nu(G)$$ then $$\forall A \in \mathcal{A}: \mu(A) = \nu(A).$$ You can find this result, for instance, in the measure theory book by René Schilling.